# Svelte: transition on reactive data change

Tags: svelte, svelte-transition

What would be the best way to trigger an animation when a reactive variable changes?
I would like to do something like this :

```html
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    let count = 0;
    const handleClick = () => count +=1
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick} transition:slide>
    Click me
</button>
<p> You cliked <strong transition:fade>{count}</strong> times</p>
```

Which doesn't work because the `<strong>`node isn't removed from the DOM (I guess). So what would be the best way to have numbers fading in and out when they change?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can now (v3.28) use the `{#key <key}` directive:

```html
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    let count = 0;
    const handleClick = () => count +=1
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Click me
</button>
<p> You cliked 
    {#key count}
      <strong in:fade>{count}</strong> 
    {/key}
    times</p>
```

***old answer***

Try this :

```html
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    let count = 0;
    const handleClick = () => count +=1
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Click me
</button>
<p> You cliked 
    {#each [count] as c (c)}
    <strong in:fade>{c}</strong> 
    {/each}
    times</p>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/03246e46f37041a39afb3c5470263560?version=3.23.2)

Comment: It is working indeed, thanks! I leave the question as seems to be a bit hacky, maybe there is a more idiomatic way to do it. I'll accept in a couple day, if not 

Comment: Accepted, can't seem to find any better way for now. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: there is now a {#key} directive. I have updated my answer

Comment: Oh that's really nice! Thanks,